# Spillway Transfer failed

Tags: websocket, predix

I am sending data from Predix Machine through spillway and websocket river, I am getting following error:

> Spillway Transfer Failed. Details: "Status for transfer UUID
>   "87ab8c74-8c34-41cb-b4ba-3666d84ad4c7" in River "WS Sender Service-1".
>     State: FAILED   Status Code: -1100

```
Status Message: Request 87ab8c74-8c34-41cb-b4ba-3666d84ad4c7 timed out".
```

What does it mean? what is the error as I am unable to find what this status code is?

Comment: -1100 is not a HTTP status code.  Have you checked the output in logs/machine/machine.log?  If you are seeing a time out, have you verified your configuration is correct?  It sounds like it could be attempting to contact an endpoint but cannot reach it.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this output from logs/machine/machine.log, I have configured Predix Machine to send data to Timeseries as well as my custom websocket. Custom websocket is accepting data from other custom client I wrote to test. Timeseries is also getting data from Predix Machine. Only error is coming with Custom Websocket.